# How can i create a link outside my webpage with the goal to open my webpage in an anchor and then load a iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried with this code but, didn´t worked.

`<a href="http://altodesign.pt/#portfolio" onClick="loadintoIframe('myframe,'portfolio/mmteam.html');">`

Comment: Might help to actually should your javascript function and to describe specifically what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

a href="javavcipt:document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'portfolio/mmteam.html';"

Answer (score 0):

I would **never use javascript** ...

I have had a look into your webpage (plenty to learn, like add scripts to the end of the page, create a global javascript object to hold all website actions, etc ... but that's not the question)

I could see that, even thought you jump to `#CONTACTOS` you are not making the use of the hash at all... and you should!

using the hash would let you do things like:

```
http://altodesign.pt/#portfolio-cooptaxis
```

and that would jump to `portfolio` anchor and load the `cooptaxis.html` into the iframe and you stoped using `javascript:loadintoIframe('myframe', 'portfolio/mmteam.html')` at all, as that will cause Google Analytics and Crawlers not to follow up your links for example ...

your method could be something simple like

```
$(function() {

    // let's see if we have an hash on the page
    var hash = document.location.hash;

    if(hash.length > 0) {
        if(hash.instr('-') >= 0) {
           // supposing will have only one char '-'
           var img = hash.split('-')[1]; 

           // let's remove the frame info from the hash
           hash = hash.split('-')[0]; 

           // there's a call to load into the iframe, let's load it
           $("#myframe").attr("src", "portfolio/" + img + ".html")
        }

        // let's fly
        jumpTo(hash);
    }

    // let's disable the anchor links by default and use the hash
    $("a[href^=#]").click(function() {
        // for all links that start with the hash, let's...
        document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
        // everytime the hash changes let's fly
        jumpTo(document.location.hash);
    });
});

function jumpTo(anchor) {
    var a = $("a[name='" + anchor.replace('#','') + "']"),
        pos = 0;
    if(a.length > 0) {
        // we have found the anchor, let's grab it's top position
        pos = a.position().top;
    }

    // if we got here and pos === 0, we did not found the anchor
    // for the given hash... maybe the user is playing around ...

    // and we shall fly
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: pos
    }, 800);
}
```

justthis will allow you to avoid using javascript to jump your links, as all they now have to have is simple: `<a href="#PORTFOLIO">Portfolio</a>`

Comment: can you help me to implement that script, i'm trying but i'm doing something wrong

Comment: falo português sim.. não tenho reputação suficiente para falar no chat

Comment: nao consigo mesmo, não tenho 20 pontos, já entrei e sai várias vezes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19361/discussion-between-balexandre-and-mauriatti)

Answer (score 0):

Let we say that you have page1.html in-which a link to page2.html you want it to be opened in an iframe in page1.html

```
in page1.html
<a href="page2.html" target="iframe-name">link</a>
<iframe name="iframe-name"></iframe>
```

Then you are able to add any anchor you want. It is just a matter of naming your iframe and then targeting it in the link!